# Prove we cannot make a homeomorphism from [0, 1] to ℝ by contradiction.

Tags: proof-writing, continuous-homomorphisms

So start off contradiction proofs by assuming the opposite.
So we assume f is a homeomorphism from ℝ to [0, 1].

Since f is a surjection, there exists some  ∈ ℝ with $f() = 0$.
Let $x_1 =  – 1$ and $x_2 =  + 1$.

Since f is an injection, and since $x_1≠ x_2 ≠ $,we know that $f(x_1) ≠ f(x_2) ≠ 0$.

Let $M = min \{ f(x_1), f(x_2) \}$.

I know I have to use the intermediate value theorem at some point but I'm stuck at the next step.

Comment: $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ are both strictly positive, and since $f$ is continuous that will violate some other property of $f$. Try drawing a sketch of the situation!

Comment: I looked at that but had a hard time understanding how they got to $f(x')=f(y')$

Comment: Think of a homeomorphism $f: \Bbb R \to [0, 1]$ and use the Intermediate Value Theorem on that, noting that for some $x, f(x)=0$.

Comment: Once you have  $f (a)=0$ the (connected) graph has to come up on both sides of  $a $, so won't pass the horizontal line test.

Answer (score 1):

Homeomorphisms are continuous. Continuous functions map compact sets to compact sets. $[0,1]$ is compact. $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact. Thus there is no continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that has image all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have such a homeomorphism.  By *Heine-Borel*, the compact subsets of  $\mathbb R $ are those that are closed and bounded.  Thus $[0,1] $ is compact and  $\mathbb R $ isn't  (unbounded).  Contradiction.

---

One can use connectedness  (IVT) to prove that there's no continuous injection from  $\mathbb R $ to $I $.  Or going in the other direction, one can just remove an endpoint to get that there's no continuous surjection.

One can also argue from compactness that there's no continuous surjection from  $I $ to $\mathbb R $.